# Infimum of $\frac{1}{\|u\|_q\|u\|_p}$ over the sphere in $H_0^1(\Omega)$.

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Consider the standard Sobolev space $H\equiv H_0^1(\Omega)$, where $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is a bounded smooth domain. Let us consider on $H$ the norm $$\|u\|^2=\int |\nabla u|^2,$$

and define $S\subset H$ by $$S=\{u\in H_0^1(\Omega): \|u\|=1\}.$$

Let $1<q<p<2^\star$ where $2^\star$ is the critical Sobolev exponent. We know that $$\tag{1}0<C_p=\inf_{u\in S}\frac{1}{ \|u\|_p},$$

and $$\tag{2}0<C_q=\inf_{u\in S}\frac{1}{\|u\|_q}.$$

So, my question is the following. Let $C_{p,q}$ be defined by $$C_{p,q}=\inf_{u\in S}\frac{1}{\|u\|_q\|u\|_p}.$$

> Is it true that $C_{p,q}=C_pC_q$?

My thoughts on the problem: The answer seems to be true to me, because of the inequality $\|u\|_{q}\le C\|u\|_p$, so it seems that when one maximizes the norm $\|u\|_q$ over $S$, the norm $\|u\|_p$ is also maximized over $S$, however, the argument is not that simple.

Any idea is aprreciated.

Comment: Here $\|u\|_p$ is the $L^p$ norm of $u$?

Comment: Yes @neal, and same for $\|u\|_q$.

Comment: One can check that the inf's in (1), (2) and in the definition of $C_{p,q}$ are attained by some functions. Then, your assertion holds if and only if there is a $u$ solving both (1) and (2). This, however, seems to be unlikely.

Comment: I think it is possible to solve (1) and (2) on an interval. Then one could check whether the solutions coincide.

Comment: Indeed @gerw, after your comment I saw that an argument with a minimizing sequence shows that we can change infimum to minimum. Now it seems that the answer to my question is negative.

Comment: @gerw, because of the inequality $\|u\|_q\le C\|u\|_p$, we have that $$\frac{1}{\|u\|_q\|u\|_p}\ge \frac{1}{C\|u\|_p^2}\ge \frac{1}{CC_p},$$ so it seems to me that the infimum is attained in the function that maximizes the norm $\|u\|_p$ over the sphere. What do you think?

Comment: I don't think so. Using this function $u$, the inequality $\|u\|_q \le C \|u\|_p$ is (most likely) not sharp.